# Get method to get the contents of the csv file

Tags: javascript

Apologies in advance as I'm very new to javascript. Essentially, I cobbled together 2 scripts and which I'm trying to get to work. I know that javascript can't normally access local files but with the `File object` it may be possible?

In the code below, if my selected file is a CSV, how can I pass it to the next function `$.get('data.csv', function(data)` so `'data.csv'` is actually the file selected?

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">

    document.getElementById('file').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelection, false);

    function handleFileSelection(evt) {
      console.log(evt);
      var f = evt.target.files[0];   
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {

      $.get('data.csv', function(data) {
        // Split the lines
        var lines = data.split('\n');

        //more code

      });

    });
</script>

<body>
    <input type="file" id="file" name="file" />
    <output id="list"></output>
</body>

</html>
```

​

Comment: Not a solution, but you're attempting to add the listener too early, the element doesn't exist yet. If you're using jQuery, use the DOMReady fn, otherwise, put it inline or add it using `window.onload`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem what I see here is that you are trying to add event listener earlier than the actual element is created (as RobG said).

And the second problem that I can mention is that you're trying to use `$.get` to parse that local CSV file. If you are using jQuery, then `$.get` makes a GET asynchronous request to some URL and it is not what you need. You have to investigate FileReader object. I am not familiar with it, so I can't bring an example of working code, but you can look for some examples [here](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/05/15/working-with-files-in-javascript-part-2/).

Comment: Thanks - the `FileReader` is exactly what I needed. I found a working example here if anyone's interested http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/